# Objective-C++ and operator ->

Tags: c++, objective-c, clang, objective-c++, clang++

I have a problem with `operator ->` and Objective-C.

I want to have C++ wrapper over ObjC class.

So I've created my class:

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@end
```

And wrapper class as well:

```
class UserWrapper {
    User *_user;
    //  ctors, accessors, etc.

    operator User *(){
        return _user;
    }

    User *operator->(){
        return _user;
    }
};
```

When I try to access backing object via `operator User*` it works good:

```
UserWrapper wrapper([User new]);
[wrapper setName:@"alex"];
NSLog(@"%@", [wrapper name]);
```

But when I try to access this object via `operator ->`

```
UserWrapper wrapper([User new]);
[wrapper setName:@"alex"];
NSLog(@"%@", wrapper->name);
```

I have the following error:

```
Property 'name' found on object of type 'User *'; did you mean to access it with the "." operator?
```

It seems that my understanding of `operator ->` is wrong.

Does somebody have an explanation about what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix this issue?

Maybe there is another way to access backing object directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, C++, and Objective-C `a->b` means to dereference `a` and access the member `b`. In C and C++ it's identical to but more straightforward than `(*a).b`.

Your implementation of `->` would therefore be correct if `User` had a member called `name`, but it doesn't. If you've written no other code at all, your `User` has an instance variable called `_name` and a setter and a getter called `name` and `setName:`. In Objective-C, this syntax:

```
value = object.name;
```

is equivalent to this syntax:

```
value = [object name];
```

i.e. that's compiled as a method dispatch that invokes the getter. Similarly, this:

```
object.name = value;
```

is equivalent to:

```
[object setName:value];
```

i.e. that's compiled as a method dispatch that invokes the setter. In neither case are you accessing the instance variable. In both cases you're calling the setter and getter. If you wanted you could implement `User` not to have an instance variable backing `name`, putting it somewhere else entirely, or to convert it to and from some other form.

The clue is that the following is valid Objective C syntax:

```
User *object = [[User alloc] init];
object.name;
```

In C and C++ the dot operator doesn't work with pointers.

It's simply not normal to expose direct member variable access in Objective-C. For a proper wrapping you'd need to write actual getters and setters for each property. The hack approach would be something like:

```
@interface User: NSObject
{
    @public
       NSString *name;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@end

[...]

@implementation User
@synthesize name;
@end
```

Which would:

- create an instance variable, `name`;
- create a setter and a getter for a property, also called `name`;
- ensure the setter and getter use the instance variable for the property;
- also expose the instance variable for direct access via `->`.

Direct instance variable manipulation is really a very bad idea though, both from a design and therefore a maintainability point of view, and in terms of allowing you to use other Objective-C features like key-value observing.